# Microsoft Power Automate Token don't refresh

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, power-automate, refresh-token, power-automate-custom-connector

I have the problem that the connection/token don't refresh.
If I used the connector after the token expires, I get 401.
The answer I get [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9wj9.png).
"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token expired at '12/04/2020 13:09:37'"",
My settings at Power Automate look like in the picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uamvq.png).
The token that I get the first time works fine.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I think you can raise a support ticket on azure portal. Azure support team will do research and help you on it. You can create the ticket by following the steps on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).